# Показывались все превью

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт и он работает не могу сделать сразу несколько превью, сейчас только одно открывается:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#photo").change(function() {
  readURL(this);

});
```

```css
.upload-file-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 94px;
  height: 94px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://pp.vk.me/c836621/v836621361/1b0f6/8SaDfr8iMGo.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.upload-file-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.upload-file-container > img {
  width: 93px;
  height: 93px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.upload-file-container-text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #719d2b;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}
.file_upload {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  width: 95px;
  top: 96px;
}
.file_upload input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>

  <div class="input-file-row-1">

    <div class="upload-file-container">
      <img id="image" src="#" alt="" />
      <div class="upload-file-container-text">


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file_upload">+
      <input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="true" class="photo" id="photo" />
    </div>
    <div id="delete">delete</div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто открыл замечательную документацию Flle Reader js заменить и html

```js
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        preview.appendChild( image );
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="browse" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```